# How well does a single data point fit a distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, bayesian, goodness-of-fit, likelihood

I have to come up with a way to measure the 'quality' of a distribution for a research project.

We collect data over a a period of time $t_0$ through $t_1$ and then estimate the distribution that fits this data. At a later time, $t_2$, we collect a single piece of data. Is there a way to measure the likelihood of the initial estimated distribution being 'correct', given this new data point?

We assume that the data points are independent random variables.

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you mean the data points independent conditioned on the generating process.  If they're totally independent, then collecting data for a period $(t_0, t_1)$ tells you nothing about any other period!

Answer (score 3):

Call your original sample $X = \{x_1, \ldots, x_n \}$. If you have a density estimate $\hat{f}(x|X)$ computed from your data, then the *likelihood* of your new data point $u$ is just $\mathcal{L}(u)=\hat{f}(u)$. Higher values of $\mathcal{L}$ imply it's more plausible that the new data point was obtained from the same underlying distribution of the original sample.

Answer (score 1):

Not without some additional assumptions.

Imagine the distribution the data are drawn from happens to consist of $n+1$ possible equally likely values, and that in $(t_0,t_1)$ you observe $n$ of those values. At time $t_2$ you observe the $(n+1)$th possible value for that distribution.

It doesn't matter *how far away* that last point is from the rest of the data, the observed sample is no more "weird" than it taking any of the other values for the last point; indeed the MLE of the distribution (the empirical cdf) is the closest possible to the true distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I see your point there...

Can you give an example of what additional assumptions might help out? E.g., If we assume it's a normal distribution? 

I was trying to use Bayes' Theorem to find the probability of it being the distribution _given_ the data point but fell down at the point where I need the probability of that distribution...

Comment: What does "more weird" mean?  Surely some values for the point at $t_2$ have higher surprisal than others given the predictive distribution.  Similarly, some distributions are more likely than others given the value for the point at $t_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let your inferred distribution from the data collected in $(t_0, t_1)$ have parameters $\theta$.  The likelihood over $\theta$ is proportional to the density of the point observed at $t_2$ given $\theta$:

$$L(\theta \mid x_{t_2}) = f(x_{t_2} \mid \theta).$$